# How to run a task after all callback is completed

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using python 3 concurrent.futures.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(do_the_work, item) for item in work_list.items()]
    for i, future in enumerate(concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)):
        status = future.result()
        print('DONE: count:{} result:{}'.format(i, status))
```

My code was written this way. But now I need to run a task after all the futures are complete. These futures write data in a shared data structure. So after all these futures are completed, I need to process the shared data structure.

I think I can rewrite the code using different threading construct. However, I am wondering is there a way to solve this problem using the concurrent.futures?

Comment: You need to use standard terminology. There are no "callbacks" in the code that you have posted. and you are not "threading." Do you mean you want to submit a new task after all the futures have completed? If so, then while still in the `with` block execute another method (e.g. `map`,  `submit`, etc.) on the `executor` object. If you mean something else, clarify your question. And why are you using `enumerate` when you are not using the `i` variable at all?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, after your `for` loop terminates all of your futures will have completed. You can now, if you wish, within the same `with` block submit additional tasks to the pool. Below I am using the `map` method to compute the square of 10 numbers and to print the results. By the way, you could have used the map method yourself.

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
    for i, status in enumerate(executor.map(do_the_work, work_list.items())):
        print('DONE: count:{} result:{}'.format(i, status))
```

But, of course, the results would be returned in the order of the items submitted and not in the order completed.

And to do additional tasks:

```py
import concurrent.futures

def square_number(x):
    return x ** 2

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(do_the_work, item) for item in work_list.items()]
    for i, future in enumerate(concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)):
        status = future.result()
        print('DONE: count:{} result:{}'.format(i, status))
    print(list(executor.map(square_number, range(10))))
```